# How to suppress a watch statement or digest cycle in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

Currently I have a text input attached to a model with a `$scope.watch` statement observing the model.  This is all used to achieve a type of auto complete / typeahead feature.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" ng-model="search.mySearchText">


// JS
var deregister = $scope.$watch('search.mySearchText', doSearch);

function doSearch() {
    mySearchService.executeSearch(search.mySearchText)
        .then(function(res) {
            // do something with the data
        });
}
```

This works fine.  However, occasionally in my `.then` function I want to make changes to `search.mySearchText`.  Obviously this would cause the watcher to be fired again, but I don't want this.

What I'm hoping to do is find a way to suppress the `$watch` from firing that next time.  Maybe by somehow telling Angular that that particular watched model property is no longer dirty?

I tried removing the `$watch` by de/re- registering the watch at appropriate times, but that didn't work either.

```
function doSearch() {
    mySearchService.executeSearch(search.mySearchText)
        .then(function(res) {
            deregister(); // shut off the watch
            search.mySearchText = 'some new string'; // manipulate the model property that I don't want to cause a search
            deregister = $scope.$watch('search.mySearchText', doSearch); 

        });
}
```

However, this didn't prevent the event firing like I expected, which is why I'm now looking for a way to suppress the event.

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually want a `$watch` then but an `ng-change` on your `<input>`?

Comment: I found [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/834), which contains two suggestions for temporarily turning off a `$watch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a variable that determines whether `doSearch` exits early, like so:

```
var searchActive = true;
function doSearch() {
    if (!searchActive) return;
    mySearchService.executeSearch(search.mySearchText)
        .then(function(res) {
            searchActive = false;
            // do manipulation of search.mySearchText
            searchActive = true;
        });
}
```